# Confused on how tensorflow feed_dict works

Tags: tensorflow

Recently started using tensorflow and I'm really confused on the functionality of feed_dict.

Looking at the mnist example from the tensorflow website, x is a symbolic placeholder that will be filled with a new batch of images every training iteration, so 'None' here could also be 'batch_size'

```
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 784])
```

when looking at the convolutional part of this tutorial, there's a command to reshape x from it's flattened 1x784 shape back to a 2D image 28x28 shape

```
x_image = tf.reshape(x, [-1,28,28,1])
```

during the training loop, x is fed through the command

```
train_step.run(feed_dict={x: batch[0], y_: batch[1], keep_prob: 0.5})
```

My question is when we feed in values to x, does tensorflow automatically vectorize every op involving x? So for example when we define the op

```
h_conv1 = tf.nn.relu(conv2d(x_image, W_conv1) + b_conv1)
```

this will automatically work across the entire batch?

if x is ndarray with each row being a flattened image, because we specified shape 'None' in the x placeholder tensorflow automatically knows to use each row as an individual training sample, and vectorize all subsequent ops?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `shape` argument is used for static shape inference (ie,`tensor.get_shape`) and is optional. TensorFlow doesn't vectorize anything automatically, but for binary cwise ops it uses [broadcasting](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html) which looks a bit like that. In your example, `tf.conv2d` is an operation that treats each row as an example, so it works with batches, but not with individual examples. Also `batch[0]` is a batch of inputs, and `batch[1]` is a batch of labels.

Comment: Ah, I think I understand, from the tensorflow api: "The convolution ops sweep a 2-D filter over a batch of images." It's not that tensorflow automatically vectorizes ops, so much as conv2d is inherently able to work on batches.